# identity server 4 windows authentication

Tags: iis, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, windows-authentication, identityserver4

I have followed a combination of these three resources for getting started with Identity Server 4.

1. [IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI)
2. [4_ImplicitFlowAuthenticationWithExternal](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/4_ImplicitFlowAuthenticationWithExternal)
3. [Combined_AspNetIdentity_and_EntityFrameworkStorage](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/Combined_AspNetIdentity_and_EntityFrameworkStorage)

The combination of the three were used in order to store users within the the database even from external providers.  Also store Identity Server 4 configurations such as claims, roles, clients, and resources.  My main issue right now is when running in IIS Express windows authentication works as expected.  Once I publish to a full IIS server on my local machine I get a repeated popup to login when I hit the Windows external login page.  I do not get that popup when running Identity Server 4 within IIS Express.  In IIS Express, I am able to click the windows external authentication button.  It routes through the app properly and successfully completes the login.

Any and all help is highly appreciated.  I tried to include as many reproduction steps as possible so let me know if there is anything not clear.

Repeating Login Popup:

[image]

IIS is setup with Windows Auth and Anonymous Auth enabled.

[image]

Setup.CS (ConfigureServices method)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        // Windows authentication is supported only by hosting Kestrel (Asp.net Core Web Server inside iis as a reverse proxy)
        // It is different than other Authentication methods because you don't Add the Authentication middleware like above.
        services.Configure<IISOptions>(options => {
            options.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc();
```

Program.cs

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I luckily answered this myself. This in fact was not a software developer issue but was an environment configuration issue. Local loopback check since the app was deployed locally was causing the issue. 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/896861/you-receive-error-401-1-when-you-browse-a-web-site-that-uses-integrate

Comment: The link is broken now, but it’s available on the Internet Archive: [https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/896861/you-receive-error-401-1-when-you-browse-a-web-site-that-uses-integrate]

Comment: This is an up to date link with same resolution steps: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/926642/error-message-when-you-try-to-access-a-server-locally-by-using-its-fqd

Answer (score 0):

Given your code works in express but not full, IIS is probably having a permission problem verifying the windows creds you are entering.  Make sure your app pool account has access to validate creds in your domain.

Comment: I am currently using my credentials for the app pool. It's I think an environment setup issue but certainly frustrating to know if it is environment or code for the environment that needs to change.

Comment: What type of account is needed to validate creds in the domain? I have been using AppPoolIdentity for a while now. I need to setup this up at somepoint too - IDSVR4 with Windows Auth.

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz Something with read access on your domain.  AppPoolIdentity is a local only account, no network requests.  I would use a domain account.  Could also use Network Service though