# Windows Authentication with IdentityServer4 on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, identityserver4, identitymodel

I am trying to use Windows Authentication credentials to connect with my native (Winforms, console app) client to Identity Server hosted on *IIS*. The point is for user to be authenticated by AD and with those credentials get the right claims and roles from the Identity Server (which is run through commercial https://commercial.abp.io/ platform).

**EDIT:
I found out it is not client related issue since i cannot use my External login (Windows credentials) even directly on hosted site.**

The thing worked locally while hosted by *IISExpress*, then i published it to *IIS* and enabled the Anonymous and Windows Authentication in the IIS settings and here is where problems began.

[image: My login screen]

When i run it and click the External Login (Windows Credentials) button i usually get a redirect to *https://myserver/Error?httpStatusCode=401*
and i get prompt for my windows credentials (which even if i insert correctly, just repeat prompt again).

[image: This is where i get after clicking the button for automatic windows authentication]

From time to time i get logged in with my Windows credentials (which is the goal). Login with username and password works fine.

I saw the similar issue mentioned by someone here:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4937 without any solution\answer.

My client is basically the sample NativeConsolePKCEClient from this  https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreWindowsAuth

```
static string _authority = "https://myserver/";
string redirectUri = "https://127.0.0.1:45656";

        var options = new OidcClientOptions
        {
            Authority = _authority,
            ClientId = "native.code",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = "openid profile",
            FilterClaims = false,
            Browser = browser,
            Flow = OidcClientOptions.AuthenticationFlow.AuthorizationCode,
            ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.Redirect,
            LoadProfile = true
        };

        _oidcClient = new OidcClient(options); 
         var result = await _oidcClient.LoginAsync();
```

and on server side the startup configuration services:

```
        private void ConfigureAuthentication(ServiceConfigurationContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        context.Services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>     // IISOptions
        {
            iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
            iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
        });

        context.Services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = configuration["AuthServer:Authority"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = Convert.ToBoolean(configuration["AuthServer:RequireHttpsMetadata"]); ;
                options.Audience = "ABPIdentityServer";
            });
    }
```

Here is the ProcessWindowsLoginAsync challenge method:

```
        private async Task<IActionResult> ProcessWindowsLoginAsync(string returnUrl)
    {
        // see if windows auth has already been requested and succeeded
        var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        if (result?.Principal is WindowsPrincipal wp)
        {
            // we will issue the external cookie and then redirect the
            // user back to the external callback, in essence, tresting windows
            // auth the same as any other external authentication mechanism
            var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                RedirectUri = "./ExternalLoginCallback",
                Items =
                {
                    { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
                    { "scheme", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme },
                }
            };

            var id = new ClaimsIdentity(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, wp.Identity.Name));
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, wp.Identity.Name));

            // add the groups as claims -- be careful if the number of groups is too large
            {
                var wi = (WindowsIdentity)wp.Identity;
                var groups = wi.Groups.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
                var roles = groups.Select(x => new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, x.Value));
                id.AddClaims(roles);
            }

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(id), props);
            return Redirect(props.RedirectUri);
        }
        else
        {
            // trigger windows auth
            // since windows auth don't support the redirect uri,
            // this URL is re-triggered when we call challenge
            return Challenge("Windows");
        }
    }
```

I am suspecting that this piece of code when calling Challenge somehow returns up redirecting to error page, but i am not sure and i do now why.

So what am i missing? Is it even possible to run both Windows and Anonymous authentication on IIS?

Here i also found similar issue:
[identity server 4 windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255110/identity-server-4-windows-authentication)

but the presented answers did not help me.

Comment: On supported platforms, you can use IdentityServer to authenticate users using Windows authentication. For more information about it, you can refer to this link: https://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/topics/windows.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, but i already tried what is on that link when i made it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that it's not the client issue it's the token provider's issue (Not the ID4 library but one where you have installed the ID4 library).

I believe that you have added the below code in the `AccountController->Login` action but ***make sure that you have added a success check in it, if you miss that then your app will go infinite loop***.

```
[HttpGet] public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
{
 if(loginViewModel.ExternalLoginScheme == "Windows")
 {
   var authenticationResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Windows").ConfigureAwait(false);
   if (authenticationResult.Succeeded && authenticationResult?.Principal is WindowsPrincipal windowsPrinciple)
   {
     // Add your custom code here
     var authProps = new AuthenticationProperties()
                {
                    RedirectUri = Url.Action("Callback"),
                    Items =
                    {
                        { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
                        { "scheme", "Windows"},
                    }
                };

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync();

    return Redirect(RedirectUri);
   }
   else
   {
     return Challenge("Windows");
   }
  }
}
```

I hope this will help you to fix your issue.
Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i already have the success checks in place, but the problem i think is somewhere else. If my credentials are for whatever reason not authenticated i am redirected to Error?httpStatusCode=401 where infinite prompt loop begins. But since credentials are taken from my domain logged in account where i am working at, i have no idea why they are refused in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anybody who might be interested. I found out what was causing the redirect error.

It is somehow connected with the ABP Suite i used for generating the base application.
there in the  ApplicationInitialization there was a middleware called

> app.UseErrorPage();

Which when the Windows credentials were challenged took it as an Error and redirected to https://myserver/Error?httpStatusCode=401.

I am not sure how this middleware works and why sometimes login worked, but removing this part solved my issue.

I hope this helps somebody, somehow, sometime..