# Is it possible to configure the forwarding of a kerberos from Nginx to kestrel aspnet core

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, kerberos

I want to deploy an ASP.NET Core application in Linux with Windows authorization.

I understand approximately what I need to configure, for example, nginx as a reverse proxy server that will forward Kerberos to Kestrel. But I don’t understand if Kestrel can accept kerberos tokens or how it needs to be configured for this scheme to work?
For IIS we need add this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

Answer (score 1):

### No official support (90% sure)

- Base on :

  - [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)
  - [HTTP.sys web server implementation in ASP.NET Core | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- Notice :

  > Windows Authentication can be configured for ASP.NET Core apps hosted with **IIS** or **HTTP.sys**.
  >
  > Windows Authentication relies on the operating system to authenticate users of ASP.NET Core apps.
- **IIS** and **HTTP.sys** only runs on Windows

### Possible Workaround

- Use Identity Server
- See [iis - How to implement Windows Authentication with IdentityServer 4 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242442/how-to-implement-windows-authentication-with-identityserver-4)